# msdeploy: Win2012R2 -> Win2012R2: "Error Code: ERROR_USER_NOT_ADMIN"

Tags: iis, msdeploy

I have used msdeploy many times, and am stumped.

On the source, I am logged in as administrator.

In the past, I have not used the "username" and "password" params on destination, as I would map a drive to destination, as a local admin user on destination. But today, the mapped drive has no effect, and I am unable to find a path forward.

- Source: in domain DOMAINNEW
- Destination: in a workgroup, not in domain
- Both are on same local subnet
- Network access to port 80 and the managemnet / web deploy port is all open.

Command:

```
msdeploy -verbose -verb:sync -source:apphostconfig="My.App Web Site",computername="APP1B" -dest:apphostconfig="My.App Web Site",computername=192.168.15.122,username=administrator,password="password",authtype=basic -enableLink:AppPoolExtension >%temp%\msdeploy-verbose-log-SITE.txt
```

Error:

```
Error Code: ERROR_USER_NOT_ADMIN
More Information: Connected to '192.168.15.122' using the Web Deployment Agent
Service, but could not authorize. Make sure you are an administrator on '192.168
.15.122'.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_U
SER_NOT_ADMIN.
Error: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
Error count: 1.
```

I have tried:

- authtype basic, ntlm, and ommitted
- creating user on source of same name and pw as admin user on destination
- passing as username and password: local admin on target, created a new user on target, no username....

Answer (score 0):

I got over this first hump. The "IIS Deployment Handler" piece of Web Deploy was not installed (see below).

Installing this piece solved the "Error Code: ERROR_USER_NOT_ADMIN"

Now on to the next error from msdeploy: [msdeploy: BACKUP_FAILED and "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40746555/147637)

[image]